# DataTables jQuery plugin removing data from first two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

When the page first begins to load, before most of the datatable styling and features have been applied, you can see data in the first two columns of my table. However, once it's complete the first to columns are blank for every row. First time using this plugin, not sure why this is happening.

**DataTable.js/jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#export').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location = '@Url.Action("ExportToCsv", "Agent")' + '?start=' + $('#startDate').val() + '&end=' + $('#endDate').val();
    });
    $("#thetable").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 50,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Filter results:"
        }
    });
    $('.dataTables_paginate').hide();
});
```

**HTML/Razor**

```
<table id="thetable" class="pretty">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TPM</th>
            <th>Bank</th>
            <th>Market Seg</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>MI</th>
            <th>SSN</th>
            <th>Agent ID</th>
            <th>Effective</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.BankName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.DRMCompanyName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Pendist)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.LastName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FirstName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.MiddleInitial)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ReferenceNumber)</td>
                <td nowrap>
                    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.AgencyId1))
                    {
                        var id = item.displayAgentIdHelper(item.AgencyId1);
                        @Html.Raw(id)                            
                    }
                </td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.EffectiveDate)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.displayStatus)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Email)</td>
            </tr>
        }    
</tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Here's a sample of the rendered HTML

```
  <table id="thetable" class="pretty">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TPM</th>
            <th>Bank</th>
            <th>Market Seg</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>MI</th>
            <th>SSN</th>
            <th>Agent ID</th>
            <th>Effective</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Whatever Financial Corp</td>
                <td> Services Inc 138675</td>
                <td>LAW</td>
                <td>BubbaOneThreeEightTwoNine</td>
                <td>BigBig</td>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>107452423239</td>
                <td nowrap>
                    04-14-9923-GR                    </td>
                <td>8/1/2013 12:00:00 AM</td>
                <td>JIT</td>
                <td>George.Tillitson@symetra.com</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Something Corp</td>
                <td>Services Inc 138675</td>
                <td>LAW</td>
                <td>BubbaOneThreeEightTwoNine</td>
                <td>BigBig</td>
                <td>D</td>
                <td>107452423239</td>
                <td nowrap>
                    11-58-0068-HW                    </td>
                <td>8/1/2013 12:00:00 AM</td>
                <td>JIT</td>
                <td>George@gmail.com</td>
            </tr>
```

**EDIT**

HEre is the entire script tag

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
    //DatePicker functions
    $(function () {
        $("#startDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
        });

        $("#endDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'
        });
    });

    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: '<%=Url.Content("~/Content/images/magnify.gif") %>',
        gotoCurrent: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
        prevText: "<< Prev",
        nextText: "Next >>"
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#thetable").dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Filter results:"
            }
        });        
        $('#export').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location = '@Url.Action("ExportToCsv", "Agent")' + '?start=' + $('#startDate').val() + '&end=' + $('#endDate').val();
        });

    });
</script>
```

**SECOND EDIT**

Here's the CSS for the table

```
/*
 * Table styles
 */
table.pretty {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

table.pretty td,
table.pretty th {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}

/* Header cells */
table.pretty thead th {
    background: #6699FF; /* #66a9bd; */
    color: white;
}

/* Body cells */
table.pretty tbody th {
    text-align: left;
    background: black;   /*#91c5d4; */
    color: white;
}

table.pretty tbody td {
    background: white; /* #d5eaf0; */
}

table.pretty tbody tr.odd td { 
    background: #e8eef4;  /*#bcd9e1; */
}

/* Footer cells */  
table.pretty tfoot th {
    background: #b0cc7f;
    text-align: left;
}

table.pretty tfoot td {
    background: #d7e1c5;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Could we see an example of some html output (instead of just the Razor template)?

Comment: It seems to be showing up ok for me... http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/2UyxB/ Maybe there's another part of the code that is responsible for the issue?

Comment: Possibly, though I'm not sure why. Just posted the entire script tag.

Comment: Just updated the fiddle and it still seems like it's showing up fine in the fiddle. Maybe something in your css somewhere else?

Comment: Taking a look, but I'm not sure how/where that would occur. Just added the CSS to the post, fyi.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42986/discussion-between-jameslafferty-and-nealr)